# Compare 2 dataframes in pandas based on column value

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have 2 data frames.
The first one `"named x"` has the following format:

```
             ISBN  Age Category  Count
20     000649840X  Middle Adult      6
21     000649840X   Young Adult     16
```

Where The same ISBN have multiple rows with different categories.

The other dataframe `"named y"` has the one row for each ISBN value. I want to create two column in the last dataframe one for each category count where the final result should look like:

```
ISBN      Middle Adult Count       Young Adult Count
```

I tried

```
y["Young Adult Count"] = x[(x['Age Category'] == 'Young Adult') & (y['ISBN] == x['ISBN])]['Count']
```

But it did not work

Comment: So `I have 2 data frames. ` means do you have second empty DataFrame and need create second from first? I am a bit confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) with [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) (default left join, so if some `ISBN` missing get `NaN`s rows) another `DataFrame`:

```
print (df1)
         ISBN  Age Category  Count
0  000649840X  Middle Adult      6
1  000649840X   Young Adult     16


print (df2)
         ISBN
0  000649840X
1  0001111111

df3 = df1.pivot_table(index='ISBN', 
                      columns='Age Category', 
                      values='Count', 
                      aggfunc='sum')
df = df2.join(df3.add_suffix(' Count'), on='ISBN')
print (df)
         ISBN  Middle Adult Count  Young Adult Count
0  000649840X                 6.0               16.0
1  0001111111                 NaN                NaN
```

For inner join use parameter `how='inner'`:

```
df = df2.join(df3.add_suffix(' Count'), on='ISBN', how='inner')
print (df)
         ISBN  Middle Adult Count  Young Adult Count
0  000649840X                   6                 16
```

Comment: Well, if OP accepted your answer then I guess it's not a dupe, so I reopened it.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - Yes, it seems so. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`groupby` + `sum` + `unstack` should work.

```
df.groupby(['ISBN', 'Age Category'])\
  .Count.sum()\
  .unstack()\
  .add_suffix(' Count')

Age Category  Middle Adult Count  Young Adult Count
ISBN
000649840X                     6                 16
```

If you want to explicitly filter on those two categories, then filter first, with `isin` -

```
cat = ['Middle Adult', 'Young Adult']
df = df[df['Age Category'].isin(cat)]
```

Now, perform the `groupby`.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks a lot

Comment: @OmarAdel Sure, don't forget to upvote both our answers, as both are good :)

Comment: @OmarAdel - so another DataFrame is not important?

Comment: @jezrael You may have misunderstood the question, I guess. OP just had an empty dataframe they wanted to populate... heheh happens a lot. English is the biggest barrier.

Comment: hmmm, but then it is only pivot dupe :(

Comment: @jezrael Huh... now that you mention it... might be!

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ - I answer only because 2 dataFrames and I think it is not pivot dupe, so why you answer? I dont understand, because your answer is clear dupe.

Comment: @jezrael Sorry dude, sometimes I make mistakes. Anyway, I have signed it now. Nothing more to do... please don't be angry.

Comment: Thanks, for you too.

Comment: @OmarAdel You can only accept one answer buddy, not both.

Comment: It's more preferable for my case to be in a new frame.

Comment: @OmarAdel Whatever works for you, but I am a bit confused since you said my answer worked perfectly.